# Edge connectivity of a graph with diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory

If G is a graph of diameter 2, then $\kappa_1(G) = \delta(G)$ where $\kappa_1(G)$ is the edge connectivity of $G$. The Chartrand/Lesniak proof goes as follows: Let $S$ be an edge cut with $|S|=\kappa_1(G)$, and let $H_1, H_2$ be the component graphs of $G-S$ with $|H_1| <= |H_2|$. Since $G$ has diameter 2, every vertex of $H_2$ is adjacent to some vertex of $H_1$. How?

I choose a vertex $u$ from $H_2$; if it's not adjacent to some vertex $v$ in $H_1$ then the graph diameter tells me there exists a vertex $w$ in $H_2$ mutually adjacent to both. So I see how *half* the vertices of $H_2$ are adjacent to vertices of $H_1$...

Comment: Yes it does sound weird.  If I take a star graph and remove a single edge, $H1$ has 1 vertex, and only one vertex of $H_2$ has neighbors in $H_1$.    Can you tell us where we can find the proof?

Comment: By that example, the $w$ of my second paragraph could be shared by all other vertices of $H_2$ invalidating my last statement. The theorem is actually credited to Plesnik (1975), an outline of which can be found on page 5 of [this document](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/teaching/ws05/graph-theory/graph-theory-3.pdf). Perhaps I'm misreading it.

Comment: The outline I linked to leaves out some steps. There's a presupposition that $H_1$ contains a vertex not incident any vertex of $H_2$, in which case all the vertices of $H_2$ are incident with vertices in $H_1$. This comes from the proof in the 4th edition of _Graphs & Digraphs_ by Chartrand and Lesniak. Even then it's not very clear. The proof in the 6th edition is much clearer. I'm posting an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are vertices $r$ in $H_1$ and $s$ in $H_2$ such that neither vertex is incident an edge of $|S|$. Then $d(r,s) >= 3$ which is a contradiction. So (without loss of generality?) if there is a vertex of $H_1$ not incident any vertex of $H_2$, it must be true that every vertex of $H_2$ is incident some vertex of $H_1$.